# PostgreSql dropping CONSTRAINT on large table extremely slow

Tags: performance, constraints, postgresql-9.2

We have a database table in PostgreSql 9.2 running on Windows with approximately 750 million rows in it.  We dropped a FK constraint on a column, but the statement has now been running for 48 hours and is still not complete.

The server has 32GB RAM and 16 CPU's.  We have unfortunately not increased the maintenance_work_mem before running the SQL statement.  It is therefore set at 256MB.  The resource on the machine are not even coming close to maximum.  As a matter of fact: CPU usage is below 3%, we have 80% of RAM free and Disk I/O does not go above 5MB/s, even though the machine can easily exceed 100MB/s.

1. Why does it take this long to drop a FK CONSTRAINT?
2. Is there a way to increase the performance of this statement execution whilst it is running?
3. What is the most efficient way of adding a FK CONSTRAINT to a table of this size?

Comment: Most probably the drop is waiting for a lock and not actually doing something. Did you check `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Yes, autovacuuming is holding the lock (to prevent wraparound).  Seems we have hit 200 000 000 mark.

Comment: You should *really* think about upgrading to a more recent version. There have been many improvements to (auto)vacuum since 9.2 was released.

Comment: You should generally also have autovacuum running more aggressively so that you don't get to the point where huge anti-wraparound vacuums are required.